# Div appear and disappear onclick in React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I want an effect like this [(before onclick)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GRH5.png)[(after oncilck)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqpVI.png).Just click on which div to make it disappear, and then let the div that disappeared before show again.

Here is the data code(just an array). I want the "show" variable in the data to control whether to display.But I don't know how to implement the destructuring assignment to the array in the click function.

Thank you for your answer!

```
const leftBarData=
[{
    name:"关于音乐",
    color:"bg-music-color",
    icon:<div className="iconMusicSize">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            blahblah
        </svg>
    </div>,
    link:"/music",
    number:0,
    show:true,
},
    {
        name:"关于编程",
        color:"bg-code-color",
        icon:<div className="iconSize">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                blah
            </svg>
        </div>,
        link:"/code",
        number:1,
        show:true,
    },
    {
        name:"关于设计",
        color:"bg-design-color",
        icon:<div className="iconSize">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                blah
            </svg>
        </div>,
        link:"/design",
        number:2,
        show:false
    },
    {
        name:"关于本人",
        color:"bg-about-color",
        icon:<div className="iconSize">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                blah
            </svg>
        </div>,
        link:"/design",
        number:3,
        show:true
    }
]
```

Here is the map.

```
const [statusData,setStatusData]=useState(leftBarData)
const changeBar=(pars)=>
    {
        how to achieve it
    }

<div className="flex fixed">
        {statusData?.map((index,i)=>(
            <Link to={index.link}>
                <div className={` ${index.color} ${index.show?"":"hidden"} w-99 h-screen pt-9 `} onClick={()=>changeBar(index)}>
                    <div className="flex flex-col h-full items-center justify-between">
                            {index.icon}
                        <div className="-rotate-90 -translate-y-full mb-10">
                            <div className="h3 text-white whitespace-nowrap">{index.name}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Link>
        ))}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map()` your state data to toggle `show` property of clicked element like this:

```js
const changeBar = pars => {
    setStatusData(data => data.map(item => (
        item === pars
        ? {
            ...item,
            show: !item.show
        }
        : item
    )));
};
```

Comment: using `map` is a very good idea but the function does not to what you want. `pars` is the index and OP wants to set `show` to `true` for the currently hidden element. With some unnecessary copies the arrow function could be `(item, idx)=>({...item, show: idx !== pars})`

Comment: @Taxel `pars` is not an index, it's an item. OP named `.map()` parameters in a confusing way, but the item is called an `index` and it's what is being passed as an argument.

Comment: You are correct. In that case, my arrow function would work with `()=>changeBar(i)`, or you could just change your condition to `item === pars || item.show === false` to also reset the hidden item

Comment: @Taxel not sure why you'd change my code. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Taxel actually I'm not sure if it's meant to only hide one item at a time or not, it's not clear from the question. I assumed that all items are toggleable.